# Escaping raw, unescaped strings in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, escaping, bookmarklet

I’m trying to write a search engine bookmarklet (for Chrome), but I’m having trouble escaping the string.

For example if the search engine bookmarklet is the following:

```
javascript:alert("%s"); //%s is the search engine query, passed literally by chrome.
```

Then running it on the following string will give incorrect results:

```
c:\zebra

c:zebra instead of c:\zebra
```

If the character after the slash happens to be an actual escape character, then the results will vary depending on the character.

I’ve tried escaping and unescaping the string, I’ve tried reg-ex’ing it, and replacing the slash with a double-slash, but I cannot figure out a way to get this to work because the first time that the raw string enters the script, it is unescaped, and any operation after that will see it incorrectly.

How can this be handled correctly?

Comment: That has nothing to do with url, but the fact that \ is an escape character in javascript. Writing `"c:\zebra"` in anywhere, will give you `"c:zebra"`. You need to write `"c:\\zebra"`

Comment: *> \ is an escape character in javascript.*   @Esailija, yes I know, that’s what I’m trying to work around.     *> You need to write*   I can’t change the string; it is provided by the user.     *> That has nothing to do with url*   Yes it does; the user enters the string in the addressbar/Omnibar.

Comment: Then I am not understanding this at all, can you show your code

Comment: `javascript:alert("%s");` already demonstrates the problem just fine. In Chrome (and other browsers), you can create a bookmarklet that is a bit of JavaScript, and you can provide it with user input (usually by using the string `%s`). The problem is that the user-provided string is entered in the JS *as is* without escaping or anything. So when the user runs the bookmarklet with `c:\zebra` (via the addressbar, or selecting text in the page, etc.) the script receives `c:\zebra`, not `c:\\zebra`.

Comment: Ok I finally figured out what you are talking about. Something like this right? http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/javascript-calculator.html

Comment: Yes, hence *bookmarklets*, except that instead of getting the data from the page, it is getting it from the URL.

Comment: Ok, I'll have something in a few minutes

Comment: @Synetech, I don’t know why two people hit-and-run down-voted. It seems like a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I can only make this work in chrome:

```
javascript: var str = (function(){STARTOFSTRING:/*%s*/ENDOFSTRING:;}).toString().match( /STARTOFSTRING:\/\*([\s\S]*)\*\/ENDOFSTRING:/ )[1]; alert(str);
```

writing c:\zebra will alert c:\zebra.

Firefox doesn't sustain the comments inside the function body when decompiled, unfortunately.

You also can't write the sequence `*/` in the string, but everything else should be passed literally, including quotes `"` `'` etc

Comment: @Synetech it's a string you passed to the "search engine"

Comment: That works for `alert`, but nothing else. What is the *object type* of `str`? I tried appending a string, using it in other types of functions, but only `alert` works.

Comment: @Synetech can you show me the code that doesn't work? It is a string.

Comment: `alert(window.atob(str))` does nothing (i.e., invalid JS). That’s true even for `str+="blah"; alert(str);`

Comment: @Synetech this search engine is working perfectly for me `javascript: var str = (function(){STARTOFSTRING:/*%s*/ENDOFSTRING:;}).toString().match( /STARTOFSTRING:\/\*([\s\S]*)\*\/ENDOFSTRING:/ )[1]; str += "blah"; alert(str);` Maybe some mispasted character? There is invisible unicode whitespace in the code you paste from StackOverflow sometimes.

Comment: Okay, got it. `btoa` requires putting the variable in quotes: `window.btoa("str");` (weird). Oops, no; that just encodes the string `str` (which makes sense).

Comment: @Synetech you will just get the base64 of that literal string `"str"`, `str` should be able to be used fine as a variable containing the written string. What error do you see in console with `window.btoa(str)`?

Comment: Nothing; nothing happens just like when there is a syntax error (Chrome aborts the operation when there is a syntax error). This however does work: `window.btoa("%s");` except that slashes are stripped because they are not escaped. No, wait; it seems to be working now. I made too many edits to be sure which one fixed it (or what the problem was).

Comment: @Synetech If I deliberately make a syntax error in the search engine, I will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } ` when I try to use the search enginge... so if you don't see any error that's incredibly weird. `javascript: var str = (function(){STARTOFSTRING:/*%s*/ENDOFSTRING:;}).toString().match( /STARTOFSTRING:\/\*([\s\S]*)\*\/ENDOFSTRING:/ )[1]; alert(window.btoa(str));` works for me fine.

Comment: It was probably an extraneous `)` at the end. Thanks a lot; this is much handier than using an online encoder/decoder. `:-)` Now if I can just figure out how to encode/decode strings as UTF-16 in JS…

Comment: I also noticed that when you update the search engine, all tabs will still use the old one before refreshed, so maybe that was a huge source of confusion here? :P

Comment: Could be; I have three or four tabs running the bookmarklet: one to encode, one to decode, one to re-encode to check, on to re-decode to check. Blerg.